# Flex: get column index in custom itemrenderer for spark datagrid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, flex4, itemrenderer

I am trying to use the same custom renderer for all the columns in a spark `DataGrid`. I need to know the `dataField` or `columnIndex` based on which I can change `state` in my custom itemrenderer.

Earlier in mx:DataGrid, this can be achieved by extending the `MXDataGridItemRenderer` which implements `IDropInListItemRenderer` and hence `dataGridListData` property is available.

But using the spark DataGrid, I am extending the `GridItemRenderer` which DOES NOT implement the `IDropInListItemRenderer` and hence unable to access `dataGridListData` property. I have tried to write an action script class extending `GridItemRenderer` and implementing `dataGridListData` but flex throws an error in the `set` function of this variable.

Can anyone help me in accomplishing this?

// Sample itemRenderer used for `mx:DataGrid` [Working Code]

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        import scripts.valueObjects.CellRendererVO;

        private var _cellRenderer:CellRendererVO = new CellRendererVO();
        [Bindable]
        private var _lineColor:uint = 0xFF0000;
        [Bindable]
        private var _lineWidth:int = 5;

        override public function set data(value:Object):void
        {
            //able to access the dataGridListData.dataField variable
            _cellRenderer = (value[dataGridListData.dataField] as CellRendererVO);
            currentState = _cellRenderer.stateName;
        }

        private function connectingLinesState_enterStateHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
        }

        protected function orgChartNodeState_enterStateHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:states>

    <s:State name="emptyState" />

    <s:State name="orgChartNodeState" enterState="orgChartNodeState_enterStateHandler(event)"/>

    <s:State name="connectingLinesState" enterState="connectingLinesState_enterStateHandler(event)"/>

</s:states>

<s:HGroup width="100%" height="100%" includeIn="orgChartNodeState"
          horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle">


</s:HGroup>

<s:HGroup width="100%" height="100%" includeIn="connectingLinesState"
          gap="0" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"
          paddingLeft="0" paddingRight="0" paddingTop="0"
          paddingBottom="0">


</s:HGroup>
```

// sample spark DataGrid itemRenderer [NOT Working]

package customComponents.myOrgChart
{
    import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridListData;
    import mx.controls.listClasses.BaseListData;
    import mx.controls.listClasses.IDropInListItemRenderer;
    import mx.controls.listClasses.IListItemRenderer;

```
import spark.components.gridClasses.GridItemRenderer;

public class TestRenderer extends GridItemRenderer implements IListItemRenderer, IDropInListItemRenderer
{

    private var _listData:BaseListData;

    public function TestRenderer()
    {
        super();
    }

    override public function set data(value:Object):void
    {
        //Flex throws error here.
        //ERROR: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
        trace('dataField: ' + DataGridListData(listData).dataField);
    }

    public function get listData():BaseListData
    {
        return _listData;
    }

    public function set listData(value:BaseListData):void
    {
        _listData = value;
    }
}
```

}

Thanks,

Anji

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Spark GridItemRenderer still has a `data` property, just as any other ItemRenderer does, so you're fine there.

What you need in addition to that is the [column](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/gridClasses/GridItemRenderer.html#column) property, which returns a [GridColumn](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/gridClasses/GridColumn.html) instance. This is the same instance you probably defined in mxml when creating the DataGrid, hence it has all its properties. The ones you'll use most are [dataField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/gridClasses/GridColumn.html#dataField) and [columnIndex](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/gridClasses/GridColumn.html#columnIndex).

For instance:

```
var value:* = data[column.dataField];
var index:int = data[column.columnIndex];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have used the column object, but still it throws the same error.

Comment: @Anji That really shouldn't happen. You're not trying to cast it to DataGridListData, are you?

Comment: Nope. This is what I am trying to do. In the set data function, I have added the line `data[column.dataField]` and I get that error

Comment: I got it working. The problem is with my dataprovider. Thanks.